# How to disable VT console when running Ubuntun 20.04 under Wayland server

Tags: xorg, wayland, kiosk, virtual-consoles

I am now running Ubuntu 20.04, and using server: Wayland. I have no idea how to disable virtual console switch under Wayland.

Under the X.org server adding this: `Option   "DontVTSwitch" "True"` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` prevents virtual console switch.

Answer (score 1):

On Gnome Wayland you can unset the keybindings for virtual terminal switching by setting these dconf properties:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-1 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-2 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-3 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-4 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-5 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-6 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-7 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-8 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-9 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-10 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-11 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-12 "['']"
```